# Is it possible to create a CNN with real output?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

The output type of the trainNetwork() must be categorical(). How can I create a CNN with float/real output(s)?

I mean the following command gives the following error:

```
>> convnet = trainNetwork(input_datas, [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], networkLayers, opts);
Error using trainNetwork>iAssertCategoricalResponseVector (line 269)
Y must be a vector of categorical responses.
```

(The error message corresponds the [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3] vector), But I need real outputs, not categories.

The networkLayers is the following:

```
>> networkLayers= 

5x1 Layer array with layers:
  1   ''   Image Input       1x6000x1 images with 'zerocenter' normalization
  2   ''   Convolution       10 1x100 convolutions with stride [1  1] and padding [0  0]
  3   ''   Max Pooling       1x20 max pooling with stride [10  10] and padding [0  0]
  4   ''   Fully Connected   200 fully connected layer
  5   ''   Fully Connected   1 fully connected layer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer takes two part

**1. Classification vs regression**
[This post describe shortly](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141386/443223) that

> Regression: the output variable takes continuous values.
>
> Classification: the output variable takes class labels.

So my problem was (when I ask the question) that I need a neural network for regression problems, not for classification.

**2. Matlab frameworks**

There are two base way to work with neural networks in Matlab.

The older framework defined the all network using a "Neural Network" class. Some base network can be built easily with this way (ex using [feedforwardnet](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html) or [layrecnet](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/layrecnet.html)), but building more complex networks is a hard work. More details building custom neural networks with the network class can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/create-and-train-custom-neural-network-architectures.html).

The newer methodology was introduced in R2016a. An introduction can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainnetwork.html). I tried to use this framework. But this framework supports regression problems only from 2017a! So This is a really new tool. But [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/train-a-convolutional-neural-network-for-regression.html) can be found a description for using the newwer framework for regression problems.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you have to change your last layer. This can be mean squared error function. [this issue explain how can you do this](https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet/issues/15)

also it is called regression. You must add loss function manually.